# How do I get an entire directory in sftp?

Tags: linux, sftp

I'm just learning to use sftp, and I want to copy a directory from the remote computer to my local computer. If I try

```
get [directory]
```

it gives me this error:

```
Cannot download non-regular file: /home/mpirocch/Documents
```

`get -R` doesn't work, either.

Comment: Recursive put/get was added to OpenSSH in 5.4, which was released in 2010. You may consider upgrading your servers as it also adds a lot of bug fixes and better security features.

Comment: Wow, sftp is basically useless as is. [`lftp`](https://superuser.com/questions/40281/how-do-i-get-an-entire-directory-in-sftp/726866#726866) helps a lot.

Comment: sftp supports now recursive mode: `get -R [directory]`

Answer (score 412, accepted):

Use the `-R` (recursive) flag:

```
get -R .
```

Comment: Thank you for putting an answer that actually answers the question.

Comment: Gives me: `get: Invalid flag -r`

Comment: This also gives me Invalid flag. I'm not sure this is supported on all systems.

Comment: @Ben: When I asked this question in 2009, the `-r` flag did not exist. Is your system up to date?

Comment: It works on all current systems. Just tested it.

Comment: @silvinci not *all* current systems. Illegal option with CentOS 6.4 openssh-clients-5.3p1-84.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: For some reason *uploading* recursively does not work with `put -r *` it can't create directories. However for me the lftp solution below worked just fine.

Comment: Anyone know the way to get -r to give directories write permissions?  Everytime I try -r on a read only directory, it will not download it because it creates the directory locally read only as well.

Comment: Not working with openssh-clients-5.3p1-111.el6.x86_64 on 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 15 08:24:23 CST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: more specifically `mget -r ./*` to get all files and folders in the current directory. works in MINGW64 too. https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=32991

Comment: It works but gives an error then skips when finding a symlink : `not a regular file`

Comment: Correct option name is `-R`. Man: If the `-R` flag is specified then directories will be copied recursively.  Note that sftp does not follow symbolic links when performing recursive transfers.

Answer (score 64):

Use:

```
scp -r mpirocch@my-server:/home/mpirocch/Documents Documents
```

Comment: This works, but it would be nice to be able to do this from SFTP (so I can see what I copy before I copy it). Is this possible?

Comment: @Matthew: I don't think so. I have been asking myself the same question for some time and the best answer that I have for the moment is `scp -r`. Or you could use an advanced SFTP client like Filezilla.

Comment: scp -r will follow symlinks...

Comment: Some systems may allow `sftp`, but not `scp` access.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EricDuminil have you seen the date? Unfortunately back then this was a good _alternative_, but if you want to be pedantic, yeah it doesn't answer the question and maybe deserves a downvote.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: It's been a while indeed, but many shared hosting servers still only allow sftp. `scp` simply isn't an alternative in this case.

Comment: @EricDuminil then take the neutral approach and don't upvote or downvote?

Comment: Please don't take downvotes personally. The description on the downvote icon is "This answer is not useful". And well, `scp` isn't useful for a question asking specifically about `sftp`.

Comment: Eric is right. I came here searching for the answer about the recursive sftp as an alternative to rsync/rcp/etc. The recommendation to use another tool is not helpful.

Answer (score 50):

Use [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/):

```
lftp sftp://user@host
```

Then, within lftp, `cd` into the directory you want to copy,
and use the `mirror` command to recursively download the selected directory,
like this:

```
mirror
```

This command accepts options and arguments:

```
mirror [OPTIONS] [source [target]]
```

For example, the `-R` (or `--reverse`) option
will cause it to upload the local directory tree to the remote directory:

```
mirror -R
```

See the `lftp(1)` man page [at the project’s site](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)
or [at Debian.org](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/lftp/lftp.1.en.html) for other commands and options.

Comment: +1 lftp is like a little bundle of magic and joy!

Answer (score 27):

well this little guide should help, mirror a remote server to local folder with lftp

`lftp sftp://user:password@server.org:22 -e 'mirror --verbose --use-pget-n=8 -c /remote/path /local/path'`

- `sftp://` = uses SFTP protocol
- `mirror` = mirror mode
- `verbose` = shows the files being downloaded
- `use-pget-n` = number of segments, realy useful to speed up big files
- `parallel` = downloads multiplier files at the same time

if you want to download files in parallel switch out `use-pget-n=8` with `--parallel=8`

hope this helps anyone needing to mirror a remote folder to a local folder

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, after the other methods failed (in particular no "-r" option on sftp). The first part of the command in my case needed to be quoted, due to dollar characters in the password `lftp 'sftp://user:pa$$word@server.org:22' -e 'mirror --verbose --use-pget-n=8 -c /remote/path /local/path'`

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I wanted to copy from local to server, so I used `mirror -R ...`

Comment: If you get `mirror: Fatal error: Host key verification failed.`, the host key fingerprint probably still needs to be accepted (i.e. use `ssh` / `sftp` to make an initial connection, and confirm the fingerprint with `yes`)

Answer (score 16):

Don't use the sftp program directly if you can find something better. For Linux, many file managers (at least Nautilus and Dolphin, the GNOME and KDE ones) support sftp natively, and there's always sshfs. For windows, there's WinSCP, and probably [others](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+sftp+client). The point of all of these is to let you access files over sftp as if they were on a regular filesytem, so you don't have to care that you're accessing them over sftp.

Comment: Wow, nautilus does work very well with SFTP. I added a bookmark in Nautilus, and now it's all ridiculously easy. Thanks!

Comment: I've had performance issue with Nautilus SFTP. Yeah, it's really convenient  but I wasn't able to saturate 1 Gbit/s network via Nautilus, while with plain `sftp/ssh` command line interface I was (cca 100 MB/s file transfers). So the issue was Nautilus on GNU/Linux Mint.

Answer (score 15):

```
get -r [directory]
```

gets `[directory]` and everything under it, where `r` stands for recursive. I found this just by typing `help` from `sftp`.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer to this question. :)

Comment: This is a duplicate of an [answer](http://superuser.com/a/216447/2357) from *Nov 29 '10* (almost one year and a half ago).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Not really. The answer you refer to recommends `get -r *` which will recursively get *everything* at the current directory level. My suggestion gets just a specific directory, which is what the OP requested. So I would argue that my answer is more accurate than the accepted answer, and I'll have my upvotes back, thankyou! ;)

Comment: Worked as a charm!

Answer (score 14):

Try `mget` instead of `get`.

Clarification: `mget` **will** work if you are inside the directory you want to copy; if you do something like this:

```
sftp> cd dir_to_get
sftp> mget *
```

it will get all the files in that directory. However, it will *not* recursively get the contents of any subdirectories.

Comment: mget doesn't work any better than get for me.

Comment: getting Cannot download non-regular file with this

Comment: This worked for me on a system where 'get -r' didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As with `cp`:

```
scp -rp user@host:/path/to/dir dir
```

The above will preserve times and modes of the original files and subdirectories. This is especially useful for the retrieval of backups.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of an [answer](http://superuser.com/a/216447/2357) from *Nov 29 '10* (almost two years ago).

Comment: This is especially useless if only `sftp` is allowed.

Comment: Also non-useful when you don't have shell access to the remote node.

Answer (score 0):

I have Java dist folder in remote server, where i have following tree:

```
- dist
--- Audio.jar
--- README
--- lib
----- lib.jar
```

Goal is: I want to use SFTP? And put them in /tmp/<>

Step 1. sftp remoteuser@ip

Step 2. cd /var/tmp

Step 2. lmkdir /tmp/dist; lmkdir /tmp/dist/lib

Step 3. lcd /tmp/dist

Step 4. mget *

Step 5. lcd /tmp/dist/lib

Step 6. mget *

Step 7. finally i have my goal

```
$ ls
Audio.jar  lib  README.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this with lftp:

```
lftp -c '
open sftp://USER:PASSWORD@remoteserver.example.com:22
mirror --verbose --use-pget-n=8 -c /remote/catalogue/ /local/catalogue/
'
```

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927303/exit-from-lftp-after-local-shell-command-execution).

Answer (score 0):

`sftp -r user@myserver:/some_remote_directory /tmp/localdir`
(it's important to specify the destination directory, otherwise it will just log in)

... worked for me (on Ubuntu 23)

or interactively:

```
sftp user@myserver
cd some_remote_directory
mget *
```

(`mget` stands for "multiple get" and the *-wildcard to get all files)