# Copy Remote Directory on Local Machine

Tags: sftp, atom-feed

Im currently using Atom's FTP package. Im just wondering if there is a way to copy a remote file directory onto my local machine (using either atom, or another tool). Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Note: The directory is on a remote server that I do not have SSH access to, only sftp. Thanks.

Comment: use https://winscp.net/

Comment: Duplicate? See https://superuser.com/questions/40281/how-do-i-get-an-entire-directory-in-sftp

Comment: Long story short, i made edits of files on a remote server and would like to pull the whole directory down to my local machine. But I am not allowed SSH direct access, only SFTP.